# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension - SSDT 2012 - Unable to connect Dynamics 365 online

Tags: ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to connect Microsoft Dynamics 365 online from SSDT 2012 through Microsoft Dynamics CRM Report Authoring extension (Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch) but I am unable to connect.

I am getting following error.

***Unable to connect to data source 'DataSource1'. The connection to server "https://Organization_Name.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc" could not be established. Make sure that the connection string and credentials are correct, and try again.***

Please see attached image.

[image]

After some googling, I have found something strange, I don't know whether it is correct or not.

It seems like, for Dynamics CRM 365 online version, we should have Microsoft Dynamics 365 Fetch into the Type drop-down in above specified image.

So, I am wondering, how to get this, because I have already downloaded the latest version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM Report Authoring extension from [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50375) link.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you input correct credentials? Also try changing the connection string into this format. "https:// crm.dynamics.com/[unique org name]"

Comment: I am inputting correct credentials and also I have tried using unique org name.